# Recursively remove pattern from filenames without changing paths

Tags: linux, bash

I have thousands of files in a directory tree with filenames like:

```
/Folder 0001 - 0500/0001 - Portrait - House.jpg
/Folder 2500 - 3000/2505 - Landscape - Mountain.jpg
```

Using linux command line I would like to remove everything up to the first word in the filenames, so "0001 - " and "2500 - ". The new filenames would look like:

```
/Folder 0001 - 0500/Portrait - House.jpg
/Folder 2500 - 3000/Landscape - Mountain.jpg
```

I have modified a script that kind of works:

```
find . -type f -name "*-*" -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; g="${f/[[:digit:]]/ -/ /}"; echo mv -- "$f" "$g"' _ '{}' \;
```

The problem here is that it butchers part of the path instead of the filename, so actual output generates filenames like:

```
/Folder  -/ /001 - 0500/0001 - Portrait - House.jpg
/Folder  -/ /500 - 3000/2505 - Landscape - Mountain.jpg
```

How can I modify this script to rename files using the pattern I described?

Comment: How does it butcher the path, can you give an example of the output you are getting?

Comment: @123, it's going to be removing digits from the path, for one.

Comment: Correct. It was removing digits from the path instead of the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name "*-*" -exec bash -c '
  shopt -s extglob
  for arg do
    dir=${arg%/*}
    basename_old=${arg##*/}
    basename_new=${basename_old##+([[:digit:]]) - }
    [[ "$basename_new" = "$basename_old" ]] && continue   # skip when no rename needed
    printf "%q " mv -- "$dir/$basename_old" "$dir/$basename_new"
    printf "\n"
  done
' _ {} +
```

You can see this code running at https://ideone.com/YJNL9c

---

- Using [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to split the directory name out from the filename allows these to be manipulated individually.

  - `${arg%/*}` removes everything after the last `/` from the variable in `arg` -- thus removing the filename, leaving the directories, when a path *has* at least one directory segment (providing this assurance is the reason for the `-mindepth 2`).
  - `${arg##*/}` removes the longest match to `*/` from the beginning -- thus removing the directories, leaving the basic filename.
- By enabling [the `extglob` shell option](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language), we get regex-like capabilities in our fnmatch/glob-style expressions, including the ability to match one-or-more of a single digit; this is why `+([[:digit:]]) -` evaluates to "one or more digits, followed by `-`".
- By using `printf '%q '` instead of `echo` when generating shell commands, we generate safely-quoted output even without control of our filenames.
- By using `-exec ... {} +`, we're passing multiple arguments to each `bash` instance, rather than invoking a separate interpreter for each file found. With `for arg do`, we iterate over all those arguments.

Comment: This is a great answer! I love the explanations of why you used what you did, this has really helped me understand what this code is actually doing. Thank you!